# Using R how can I extract strings from a dataframe row which are contained in a list?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe where I want to extract any word in a row which matches a provided list. I'd like those matches to be extracted to a new column.

```
zoo <- matrix (c("zoo1", "bee", "honeybee", "alligator", "tiger", 0,  
             "zoo2", "tiger", "honeybee", "lion", 0, 0,
             "zoo3", "alligator", "alligator", "alligator", 
           "bee", "wasp", "zoo4", "wasp", "honeybee", 0, 0, 0,
           "zoo5", "alligator", "lion", "tiger", "bear", 0), 
           nrow = 5, ncol = 6, byrow = TRUE)

colnames(zoo) <- c("zoo", "A", "B", "C","D","E")

zoo <- data.frame(zoo)
```

For my new column, I want to search each zoo row and extract matches from this list

`bug <- c("bee", "wasp", "honeybee")`

My ideal output for this dataframe:
`zoo$bug_extract<- c("honeybee, wasp", "honeybee", "bee, wasp", "wasp, honeybee", "")`

Thank you.

I can generate the count of bug list matches, but not extract the strings themselves

`rowSums(sapply(zoo[,animal], function(x) x %in% bug))`

Answer (score 3):

**Base R**:

1. With `apply` we check if the bug list items match with each of the columns `2:6`.
2. With the `paste` function we concatenate if we found a match to the new column `bug_extract`

```
zoo$bug_extract <- apply(zoo[,2:6], 1, function(x) paste(x[x %in% bug], collapse = ', '))
```

**Tidyverse approach:**

1. Here we use `across` to check columns `2:6` if there is a match with the bug list. (trick: names argument to later unite all with ->
2. Using `unite` we concatenate all columns to one -> `bug_extract`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

zoo %>% 
  mutate(across(A:E, ~case_when(. %in% bug ~ .), .names = 'new_{col}')) %>%
  unite(bug_extract, starts_with('new'), na.rm = TRUE, sep = ' ')

   zoo         A         B         C     D    E   bug_extract
1 zoo1       bee  honeybee alligator tiger    0  bee honeybee
2 zoo2     tiger  honeybee      lion     0    0      honeybee
3 zoo3 alligator alligator alligator   bee wasp      bee wasp
4 zoo4      wasp  honeybee         0     0    0 wasp honeybee
5 zoo5 alligator      lion     tiger  bear    0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `map` with `rowwise`/`c_across`:

```
library(tidyverse)

zoo |> 
  rowwise() |> 
  mutate(bug_extract = paste(bug[map_lgl(bug, \(b) b %in% c_across(A:E))], collapse = ", "))

# A tibble: 5 × 7
# Rowwise: 
  zoo   A         B         C         D     E     bug_extract             
  <chr> <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr> <chr> <chr>           
1 zoo1  bee       honeybee  alligator tiger 0     "bee, honeybee" 
2 zoo2  tiger     honeybee  lion      0     0     "honeybee"      
3 zoo3  alligator alligator alligator bee   wasp  "bee, wasp"     
4 zoo4  wasp      honeybee  0         0     0     "wasp, honeybee"
5 zoo5  alligator lion      tiger     bear  0     ""
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit similar to @andrew_reece's answer, bit with `toString`(a bit more straightforward), and using `purrr::keep` for the subsetting.
`c_across` creates a vector, which we can subset with brackets or subsetting functions like keep:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

zoo |>
    rowwise() |>
    mutate(bug_extract = toString(c_across(A:E) |>
                                      keep(~.x %in% bug)))

# A tibble: 5 × 7
# Rowwise: 
  zoo   A         B         C         D     E     bug_extract     
  <chr> <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr> <chr> <chr>           
1 zoo1  bee       honeybee  alligator tiger 0     "bee, honeybee" 
2 zoo2  tiger     honeybee  lion      0     0     "honeybee"      
3 zoo3  alligator alligator alligator bee   wasp  "bee, wasp"     
4 zoo4  wasp      honeybee  0         0     0     "wasp, honeybee"
5 zoo5  alligator lion      tiger     bear  0     ""
```

Comment: `keep` is great here! Nice solution.